# How to show a Chart when an item on a dropdown is selected in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I want to show different chart whenever an item on a dropdown is clicked. I was able to create a sample program with a dropdown using Picker and show a box view depending on the item selected. But now, instead of boxes, i want a Chart to be shown. Can somebody tell me how? I don't have any background in creating charts in Xamarin.Forms. Here's the code of my sample program.

SampleProgram.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class SampleProgram : ContentPage
{



    // Dictionary to get Color from color name.
    Dictionary<string, Color> nameToColor = new Dictionary<string, Color>
    {
        { "Aqua", Color.Aqua }, { "Black", Color.Black },

        { "White", Color.White }, { "Yellow", Color.Yellow }
    };



    public SampleProgram()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Title = "Expense";
        BackgroundImage = "bg3.jpg";

        //Label header = new Label
        //{
        //    Text = "Picker",
        //    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
        //    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        //};

        Picker picker = new Picker
        {
            Title = "Color",
            //VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        foreach (string colorName in nameToColor.Keys)
        {
            picker.Items.Add(colorName);
        }

        // Create BoxView for displaying picked Color
        BoxView boxView = new BoxView
        {
            WidthRequest = 150,
            HeightRequest = 150,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (picker.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                boxView.Color = Color.Default;
            }
            else
            {
                string colorName = picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex];
                boxView.Color = nameToColor[colorName];
            }
        };

        // Accomodate iPhone status bar.
        this.Padding = new Thickness(5, Device.OnPlatform(10, 0, 0), 5, 2);

        // Build the page.
        this.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                //header,
                picker,
                boxView
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Just have them all in your layout and change visibility depending on your selection

Comment: chart means what ? a listview (or tableview ?) , if yes , will this listview rows entries  be different for different row selection of picker ?

Comment: Charts, I mean Graphs.